# Node.js Ubuntu server refusing socket connections after about 1000-3000 concurrent connections

Tags: linux, node.js, sockets, ubuntu, concurrency

I am testing to see how many concurrent sockets I can have connected to my server ( 4th generation 6-core intel with 12 GB of RAM ). I am writing the application in Node.js. The server simply accepts a connection and then it tells me how many concurrent connections are connected. The client simply creates a socket and connects. In the client I am trying to create 15,000 concurrent connections but the server seems to fail (connections refused) after anywhere between 1000 - 3000 connections. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 for my server and have upped my soft and hard limits to 100,000 in the /etc/security/limits.conf file.

```
myUser      hard    nofile      100000
myUser      soft    nofile      100000
```

I am not sure what is causing the problem, how do I allow more concurrent users? I am pretty sure it is not a hardware limitation as I believe 12GB of ram should be able to connect much more than 1000-3000 connections.

My Client file:

```
var net = require('net');

var HOST = '192.168.1.83';
var PORT = 5000;



for (var i=0; i<15000; i++){


var client = new net.Socket();
client.connect(PORT, HOST, function() {

    console.log('CONNECTED TO: ' + HOST + ':' + PORT); 


});


client.on('data', function(data) {



});

// Add a 'close' event handler for the client socket
client.on('close', function() {
    console.log('Connection closed');
});

}
```

My Server file:

```
// Load the TCP Library
var net = require('net');



// Keep track of the chat clients
var clients = [];

var numClients = 0;

// Start a TCP Server
net.createServer(function (socket) {

  // Identify this client
  socket.name = socket.remoteAddress + ":" + socket.remotePort ;

  // Put this new client in the list
  clients.push(socket);

  // Send a nice welcome message and announce
  socket.write("Welcome " + socket.name + "\n");


  numClients++;
  console.log(numClients);

  // Handle incoming messages from clients.
  socket.on('data', function (data) {

  });

  // Remove the client from the list when it leaves
  socket.on('end', function () {
    clients.splice(clients.indexOf(socket), 1);


    numClients--;
    console.log(numClients);

  });

  // Send a message to all clients
  function broadcast(message, sender) {
    clients.forEach(function (client) {
      // Don't want to send it to sender
      if (client === sender) return;
      client.write(message);
    });
    // Log it to the server output too
    process.stdout.write(message)
  }

}).listen(5000);

// Put a friendly message on the terminal of the server.
console.log("Chat server running at port 5000\n");
```

Comment: Have you double checked that the limits are in fact in effect? You should be able to verify this with `console.log(fs.readFileSync('/proc/self/limits', 'utf8'));` inside your node script.

Comment: The "Max Open Files" has a limit of 4096? It seems as if the changes did not occur. Inside the limits.conf file the 100000 is still there. I have also added the pam_limits.so to the /etc/pam.d/common-session file and have restarted the server, but the limit of 4096 still shows?

Comment: If you do have `session required pam_limits.so` in your `/etc/pam.d/common-session` file, how are you starting your script (as this particular user with the custom limits)?

Comment: I am simply calling my script as: "node socketServer.js" in the terminal

Comment: Hmm, if you're logged in as `myUser`, then try exiting and re-opening the terminal and trying again. I have a similar pam_limits setup as you on Ubuntu 14.04 and my limits take effect.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work. The OS is running inside VMware, but I do not think this has anything to do with it.